# Is a given function Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis

Define $g: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

\begin{equation*}g(x,y) =
\begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} &\mbox{for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ g(0,0) = 0. \end{cases}\end{equation*}

I am trying to decide whether or not $g$ is Lipschitz.  I was having a bit of trouble showing that it either is or isn't directly, but now I suspect that it is not Lipschitz simply because it is not continuous at $(0,0).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function is Lipschitz, it is continuous.

Choose $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $g(\frac{1}{n},\alpha \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}$. By choosing $\alpha$ appropriately, we have $\{g(\frac{1}{n},\alpha \frac{1}{n}) \}_\alpha = [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$. Hence $g$ is not continuous at $x=0$, hence it cannot be Lipschitz continuous.

However, for any $(x,y) \neq 0$, we have $Dg((x,y)) = \frac{(y-x)(y+x)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}(y,-x)$. If we choose $R>0$, then if $(x,y) \in B(0,R)^c$, we have $\|Dg((x,y))\| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}$, and hence $g$ is Lipschitz on $B(0,R)^c$ (by the mean value theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  What happens as you approach $(0,0)$ along the curve $y = x$?